# How do I implement formulas of permutations and combinations in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What did I do wrong in my code?

PS: nPr=n!/(n-r)!  nCr=nPr/r!

```
def f(a):
    fact = 1
    for i in range(1, a+1):
        fact = fact*i
    return fact


def main(n, r):
    x = n - r
    p = f(n)/f(x)
    print(p)
    c = f(n)/f(x)*f(r)
    print(c)

main(3, 2)
```

Comment: It's indented wrong on the first line. Is that what you're asking about or do you want to be more specific about your problem?

Comment: You'll need some brackets in your nCr calculation

Comment: The standard Python library already have those implemented. Take a look at [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).

Comment: Take a look also at ['math.factorial'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.factorial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `c=f(n)/f(x)*f(r)` you have made a false assumption that `a / b * c = a / (b*c)`, hence the strange results you get for the number of the combinations. The correct code would be:

```
def f(a):
    fact=1
    for i in range(1,a+1):
        fact=fact*i
    return fact


def main(n,r):
    x=n-r
    p=f(n)/f(x)
    print(p) 
    c=f(n)/ (f(x)*f(r))
    print(c)

main(3,2)
```

will give you:

```
6
3
```

otherwise you may:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.permutations(range(3),2))
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
>>> list(itertools.combinations(range(3),2))
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
```